# How Can I resolve [Errno 13] Permission denied:?

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm a newbie of Apache + mod_wsgi + flask application developer.

Today, I'm trying to solve the curious problem.

The problem is that it fails to read the json file.

The error is below.

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/settings/sample.json'
```

Here's my Apache settings of httpd.conf.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi user=apache group=apache threads=2
WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/http/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /srv/http:/usr/local/settings

<Directory "/srv">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/local/settings">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I tried two different test cases before asking this.

Case 1: Success

Relative path access of json file which locates on `/srv/http/sample.json`.

Note that the files `sample.json` between `/srv/http/` and `/usr/local/settings` are same permissions.
However, the ladder was failed to read.

Case 2: Failed

Use absolute path to read `sample.json` instead of relative path in python script.

In both cases, SELinux alert did not appeared.

And this is my environment.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.9.10
$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.51 (CentOS Stream)
Server built:   Jan 10 2022 00:00:00

mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.9 configured
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does the user or group `apache` have access rights to your files on the file system?

Comment: Yes, it was the same permissions when I tried to do case #1. `apache` had the rights. The owner of the directories is `apache` and both permissions are 0755. (I also tried to the same case chaning permission to 0777 and failed.)

Comment: I've just figured out that SELinux prevented the access of the file. I'll check my configuration and make a policy. Thanks.